# BigCommerce API - Google Shopping

Tags: api, bigcommerce

Is there a way to retrieve "Google Shopping" field like Color, Manufacturer Part Number, Size etc from the BigCommerce API?

Thanks,

Brij

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you retrieve the `Google Product Search Mappings` subresource for the product:

https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/objects/v2/google_product_search_mapping

For example, the following endpoint would give you the data you're after:

```
GET /stores/{store_hash}/v2/products/{product_id}/googleproductsearch
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like it, but there's a workaround in this SO question/answer:

[Accessing Google Shopping Fields via BigCommerce API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20707250/accessing-google-shopping-fields-via-bigcommerce-api)