# Accessing Google Shopping Fields via BigCommerce API

Tags: bigcommerce

I am creating a custom integration with a third party part supplier to create products in their inventory in BigCommerce. I Need the ability to turn on google shopping for the products imported and add the MPN and category, but i don't see how to modify this in the API. If anyone has any feedback please let me know!

Comment: Please include a reason why you're downvoting if you're going to do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after contacting BigCommerce about this issue. The API does not have access to the Google shopping fields. Bummer. However as a workaround you can generate an import file with just product ids and the required fields listed in [this nice tutorial](https://support.bigcommerce.com/questions/1062/How+do+I+import+products+and+product+options+with+a+CSV+file?). Follow the remaining steps in the guide to find the fields for the google shopping tab (they all start with GPS) and then add your values to a csv.

My script will actually generate the csv when a new product is added via the api, and send it to the client for upload. Which isn't too much of a hassle when inventory items do not change frequently.

Comment: I believe this is now possible via the API: https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/objects/v2/google_product_search_mapping