# BigCommerce API v3 - Google shopping with BigCommerce API v3

Tags: bigcommerce

I am working with the v3 of the BigCommerce API and need to find a way to update or on-create the field for google shopping fields for each product.

There is a GET googleproductsearch in v2 but no documentation on updating seem to find an update path

I have tried following this thread:
[Accessing Google Shopping Fields via BigCommerce API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20707250/accessing-google-shopping-fields-via-bigcommerce-api)

Does anyone know what the endpoint to update or create a google shopping setting onto an item using the API instead of the site:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Google Shopping feed functionality is currently being sunset and isn't included in V3 Catalog APIs, which is likely why documentation for an endpoint was removed. I was able to see the Allow Headers only includes GET, HEAD, and OPTIONS so it doesn't look like modifying these fields is possible via API. You can use a CSV import to accomplish this, and you can find more info about that here: https://support.bigcommerce.com/s/article/Importing-Exporting-Products#table